# How to blur an image in one specific direction in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, filter, blur

I have an image and I would like to blur it in one specific direction and distance using Matlab.

I found out there is a filter called `fspecial('motion',len,theta)`.

Here there is an example:

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
imshow(I);
H = fspecial('motion',20,45);
MotionBlur = imfilter(I,H,'replicate');
imshow(MotionBlur);
```

[image]

However the blurred picture is blurred in 2 directions! In this case 225 and 45 degrees.
What should it do in order to blur it just in a specific direction (e.g. 45) and not both?

Comment: I’m wondering what you think that would look like?

Comment: Do you mean it's blurred in 45 degrees and 225 degrees? The image I see isn't blurred at -45 degrees.

Comment: @AngerDensity sorry yes you are correct! I edit immediately

Comment: @CrisLuengo The blur should happen as if i took a fresh painting and spread the colors just in one direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want what's called a ["comet" kernel](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/convolve/#comet). I'm not sure what kernel is used for the "motion" blur, but I'd guess that it's symmetrical based on the image you provided.

Here is some code to play with that applies the comet kernel in one direction. You'll have to change things around if you want an arbitrary angle. You can see from the output that it's smearing in one direction, since there is a black band on only one side (due to the lack of pixels there).

```matlab
L = 5; % kernel width
sigma=0.2; % kernel smoothness

I = imread('cameraman.tif');
x = -L:1.0:L;

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,x);
H1 = exp((-sigma.*X.^2)+(-sigma.*Y.^2));
kernel = H1/sum((H1(:)));

Hflag = double((X>0));
comet_kernel = Hflag.*H1;
comet_kernel=comet_kernel/sum(comet_kernel(:));

smearedImage = conv2(double(I),comet_kernel,'same');

imshow(smearedImage,[]);
```

[image: Add image output]

**Updated code**: This will apply an arbitrary rotation to the comet kernel. Note also the difference between `sigma` in the previous example and `sx` and `sy` here, which control the length and width parameters of the kernel, as suggested by Andras in the comments.

```matlab
L = 5; % kernel width
sx=3;
sy=10;
theta=0;

I = imread('cameraman.tif');
x = -L:1.0:L;

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,x);
rX = X.*cos(theta)-Y.*sin(theta);
rY = X.*sin(theta)+Y.*cos(theta);
H1 = exp(-((rX./sx).^2)-((rY./sy).^2));
Hflag = double((0.*rX+rY)>0);
H1 = H1.*Hflag;
comet_kernel = H1/sum((H1(:)))

smearedImage = conv2(double(I),comet_kernel,'same');

imshow(smearedImage,[]);
```

Comment: This looks pretty interesting... what do you mean with change things around... where exactly?

Comment: You would want to select `Hflag` indices only around a certain angle. I'm not sure how to do it easily off the top of my head, though.

Comment: I'm not an image processing person but I'd think that using a `sigma_x` and `sigma_y` in the Gaussian with values that correspond to a flat ellipsoid rotated in the right direction should work, cc @FedericoGentile. I.e. take `sigma_x = small; sigma_y = large;` (note that `sigma` here is the reciprocal of the usual `sigma`), then make a coordinate transform to get a matrix-valued `[sigma_xx, sigma_xy; sigma_yx, sigma_yy]` (so at the end you have a 2x2 matrix of sigmas in the exponent).

Comment: Yeah, the key is to have the kernel asymmetrical. I suspect the "motion" blur uses a symmetric and probably ellipsoidal kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Anger Density's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57328180/5211833) I wrote this code that solves my problem completely:

```matlab
L = 10; % kernel width
sx=0.1;
sy=100;
THETA = ([0,45,90,135,180,225,270,320,360])*pi/180;
for i=1:length(THETA)

    theta=(THETA(i)+pi)*-1;

    I = imread('cameraman.tif');
    x = -L:1.0:L;

    [X,Y] = meshgrid(x,x);
    rX = X.*cos(theta)-Y.*sin(theta);
    rY = X.*sin(theta)+Y.*cos(theta);
    H1 = exp(-((rX./sx).^2)-((rY./sy).^2));
    Hflag = double((0.*rX+rY)>0);
    H1 = H1.*Hflag;
    comet_kernel = H1/sum((H1(:)));

    smearedImage = conv2(double(I),comet_kernel,'same');

     % Fix edges
    smearedImage(:,[1:L, end-L:end]) = I(:,[1:L, end-L:end]); % Left/Right edge
    smearedImage([1:L, end-L:end], :) = I([1:L, end-L:end], :); % Top/bottom edge

    % Keep only inner blur
    smearedImage(L:end-L,L:end-L) = min(smearedImage(L:end-L,L:end-L),double(I(L:end-L,L:end-L)));


    figure
    imshow(smearedImage,[]);
    title(num2str(THETA(i)*180/pi))
    set(gcf, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'OuterPosition', [0 0 1 1]);
end
```

Comment: I think you actually keep only the inner blur now, and that only at points where the blur results in a darker pixel than the original image. Wouldn't `smearedImage2 = I; smearedImage2(L:end-L,L:end-L) = smearedImage(L:end-L,L:end-L)` be a more cost effective way to achieve removing the blur on the outer edges, whilst keeping *all* blur on the inside? (Swap `I` and `smearedImage` to bur only the edges as alternative).

Comment: @Adriaan yes I agree... maybe something like this right?

Comment: That's more or less what I suggested, yea. The "inner blur" though, is still not "inner", it's simply keeping the darker of the two pixels between (un-)blurred images. Also I think this solution digresses quite a bit beyond the initial question, especially since this is a loop around the accepted answer with extra functionality; functionality not asked for in the OP.

Comment: I just added this answer for sake of completeness cuz it can help to just copy paste this answer to solve the original problem i had in mind

Comment: Sure, I get that, but that's just for you. No-one else knows the original problem you had in mind, as we are not clairvoyant. All we can see it the problem you asked about (and which was solved in the other comment). You'd need to edit the answer to explain which additional functionality is present in this answer with respect to what was initially asked for by you.